# Garageband - Importing mp3 at correct tempo

Tags: garage-band

I am trying to import a song (mp3) into garage band, to use as a backing track.

I managed to get it in, but it is super sped up. Like chipmunks on steroids.

The whole track looks squished together and I'm not sure how to fix it!

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Per Apple - GarageBand plays everything at a sample rate of 44.1K. If you import something recorded at a sample rate of 48K it will play slower and at a lower pitch in GB. If you import something sampled at a rate of 22K, it will play faster and at a higher pitch in GarageBand. Try this: Drag the sound file into the iTunes window, if it isn’t already there. Set your Import preference to AIFF, 44.1K, 16-bit. With the name selected in the iTunes window choose Create AIFF Version from under the Advanced menu. When the conversion is completed a new file will be created and listed in the iTunes window (in older versions of iTunes the Create menuItem was called Convert, and Convert didn’t actually convert, it recreated in the new format). Select this new iTunes song and choose Show In Finder from under the File menu. Drag this new file into your GarageBand Timeline and it will play fine. - it's from an older version of apple garageband but should work for you.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. Funnily, the mp3 was bounced by me using Logic. Sent it to a friend and it wouldn't play at the correct speed in GB. We solved it by using a .wav bounce. Making sure the imported file has a 44.1K sample rate is the correct answer.

Comment: Dave there are changes in new updates to GB. Could you share what release of GB you are using, as well the Mac OS? The steps could be different for you now.