# Importing backing track in at correct tempo

Tags: garage-band

I'm trying to drop and drag a backing track, that is already playing correctly in 'Music' (iTunes has gone) into GarageBand 10.2. But it has sped up and I don't know how to drop and drag it, and have it sounding like it should. I've checked the original is at the proper speed - and it plays properly on my phone and computer.

(A similar question asked 2 years ago suggested using iTunes - but now its 'Music' and seems to be different so that hasn't helped me. My computer is running Catalina.  Help - any suggestions ... I'm new to GarageBand!

Comment: Can you check in Music what the sample rate of the file is? In the long list 'Songs' view, right click any column header & add 'Sample Rate' if you don't see it already. As far as I'm aware, GB can only play at 44.1 kHz, so if your file is different you're going to have to convert it in another app first.

Comment: Thx Tetsujin ... Im trying - right clicking on column headers isn't doing anything and I don't seem to have the opportunity of adding 'sample rate'. Very frustrating eh.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Garageband - Importing mp3 at correct tempo](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/97746/garageband-importing-mp3-at-correct-tempo)

Comment: Ive found it!!!! It is 44.1 kHz - so that is correct. But it is sooo fast after I drag and drop from song list into Garageband. Is drag and drop not the way to do it?